# Add another property to all objects in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Sorry new to typescript, I have this array of object, i need to insert another property `type` with value `Customer` for all objects.

```
//this is printed out in browser's developer mode, that's why the index is there
0: {name: "Ken", address: "USA"}
1: {name: "Peter", address: "USA"}
```

In the final array, it will be:

```
0: {name: "Ken", address: "USA", type: "Customer"}
1: {name: "Peter", address: "USA", type: "Customer"}
```

Something like:

```
this.users.forEach(function (user) {
    user.type: "Customer"
});
```

Tried to search around but not able to find the answer, how do i achieve the above?

Comment: Your sample is almost correct, just replace `:` to `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 this.users = this.users.map(item => ({...item, type: "Customer"}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
this.users = this.users.map(function (user) {
    user.type =  "Customer"
    return user;
});
```

Comment: Why use `map()` instead of `forEach()`? You're mutating the objects itself anyway.

Comment: forEach is fine here too. I just tend to use map whenever I am mutating an object. It helps me detect where I am mutating objects in code easily

Answer (score 0):

Change your `user.type: "Customer"` to `user.type = "Customer"` and it should work

```js
let users = [{name: "Ken", address: "USA", type: "Customer"}]

users.forEach(function (user) {
    user.type = "Customer"
});

console.log(users)
```